GregorioTex doesn't let me change the color of the separating line between columns
I'm using the paracol package to set up a bilingual text in a document in which I'm using the gregoriotex package. I want to change the color of the separating vertical line, but I can't. By my tests, I discovered that things get troublesome when I add gregoriotex to my preamble. It seems that there is a conflict between paracol and gregoriotex, and the vertical line remains black. Any help would be appreciated.
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{paracol,xcolor}
\usepackage[autocompile]{gregoriotex}
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.5pt}
\colseprulecolor{red}

\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2}
\lipsum[1]
\switchcolumn
\lipsum[1]
\end{paracol}

\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SE. Please add a minimal but complete compilable example that reproduces your issue, including documentclass and begin and end document

The issue is with luacolor which is loaded by gregoriotex. Replacing \usepackage[autocompile]{gregoriotex} with \usepackage{luacolor} shows the same issue

Possibly related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/493104/208544

Thanks to mbert's comment, I knew that the problem was with luacolor, so I started to search about it and came across this: https://github.com/ho-tex/luacolor/issues/9. I've tried it and it's working well. At this moment, I don't know if there are any side effects. Anyway, it seems necessary to redefine some package's attributes.
Here goes a new MWE (fixed problem):
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{paracol,xcolor}
\usepackage{gregoriotex}
\usepackage{lipsum}  

\ifluatex
\usepackage{luacolor}
\directlua{
 resetboxcolor = function (head,color)
  for n in node.traverse(head) do
    if 
      node.has_attribute(n,oberdiek.luacolor.getattribute(),
        oberdiek.luacolor.getvalue(token.get_macro("default@color")))
    then 
      node.set_attribute(n,oberdiek.luacolor.getattribute(),color)      
    end
    if n.id == node.id("hlist") or n.id == node.id("vlist") then
     resetboxcolor (n.list,color)
    end
 end
 return head
 end 
}

\protected\def\luacolorresetboxcolor#1{%
  \directlua {local color= tex.getattribute(oberdiek.luacolor.getattribute())
              resetboxcolor (tex.getbox(\the#1),color)}}

\else
\protected\def\luacolorresetboxcolor#1{}
\fi
  
\usepackage{paracol,etoolbox}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.5pt}
\colseprulecolor{red}

\makeatletter 
\patchcmd\pcol@hfil
 {\copy\pcol@tempboxa}
 {\luacolorresetboxcolor\pcol@tempboxa\copy\pcol@tempboxa}{}{\fail}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2}
\lipsum[1]
\switchcolumn
\lipsum[1]
\end{paracol}

\end{document}

